# Windows AMIs with .NET 4?

Tags: .net-4.0, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

Are there any **Amazon-provided** Windows AMIs that have the .NET 4 framework pre-installed? Unless I'm missing something, it looks like 3.5 is available on the images (such as [ami-cab91da3](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/amazon-ebs-backed-windows-server-2008-r2-english-64-bit-sql-2012-express)), but not .NET Framework 4.

If not, can we expect updates to the AMIs to include .NET 4 in the near future? It's been officially released for almost two years at this point. Or am I responsible for installing it and building (and maintaining) a custom AMI?

(cross-posted from [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=345680))

Answer (score 1):

The 'official ' [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) AMIs for running [Windows Server & SQL Server on Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/) (likely with Microsoft being involved in these offerings) primarily mirror respective official OS offerings from Microsoft (plus server versions eventually, like SQL Server or IIS). Therefore the [.NET Framework 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_4#.NET_Framework_4) will only be pre-installed if either the provided OS (plus service pack) or the installed servers do require and respectively provide it as their default configuration.

That is the case with the recently [Updated Microsoft SQL Server Offerings](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/05/updated-microsoft-sql-server-offerings.html) indeed, insofar [SQL Server 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2012) requires the .NET Framework 4 indeed, see [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx). Section *Support for Microsoft SQL Server 2012* lists the respective AMI catalog entries accordingly:

> SQL Server 2012 Express ([AMI catalog entry](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/amazon-ebs-backed-windows-server-2008-r2-english-64-bit-sql-2012-express))
>   SQL Server 2012 Web Edition ([AMI catalog entry](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/amazon-ebs-backed-windows-server-2008-r2-english-64-bit-sql-2012-web))
>   SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition ([AMI catalog entry](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/amazon-ebs-backed-windows-server-2008-r2-english-64-bit-sql-2012-standard))